# Cannot initialize database while using an Oracle for jhipster application

Tags: oracle11g, jhipster

I'm trying to use a Oracle database for jhipster development in production mode.
My database configuration is

```
profiles:
    active: prod
datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    dataSourceClassName: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.01:49161:xe
    databaseName:
    serverName: 
    username: vpp_owner
    password: vpp_owner

jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10GDialect
    database: ORACLE
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

The Oracle server is up and running and I'am able to connect to the database with the given credentials.
After mvn -Pprod mvn-boot:run I got the following  SQLException

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
 [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE VPP_OWNER.JHI_USER (id NUMBER(38, 0) DEFAULT SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL NOT NULL, login VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(60), first_n
ame VARCHAR2(50), last_name VARCHAR2(50), email VARCHAR2(100), activated NUMBER(1) NOT NULL, lang_key VARCHAR2(5), activation_key VARCHAR2(20), reset_key VARCHA
R2(20), created_by VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, reset_date TIMESTAMP, last_modified_by VARCHAR2(50), last_modified_da
te TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT PK_JHI_USER PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (email), UNIQUE (login))]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1247)
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1230)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:548)
        ... 115 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:931)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1792)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1745)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:334)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementProxy.execute(StatementProxy.java:83)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.StatementJavassistProxy.execute(StatementJavassistProxy.java)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
        ... 120 more
```

The problem seems to be the DEFAULT SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL NOT NULL expression.

Any hints hat is going wrong ?

I'm using jhipster 2.19.0 and Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Oracle 11g.

From the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#sthref7262

> A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to PL/SQL functions or
>   to other columns, the pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, PRIOR,
>   and ROWNUM, or date constants that are not fully specified.

Such a statement is only usable with Oracle 12c or higher:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1

Answer (score 0):

When I apply some changes to the generated sources I am able to use an 11G database.

1. In User.java replace GenerationType.SEQUENCE with GenerationType.AUTO for the id field.
2. In der liquibase changelog files remove the defaultValueComputed attributes for all id fields.
3. remove the table specific sequences
4. do not remove the hibernate_sequence from the "base" changelog ;-)

May be this could be included in the jhipster generator ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Moh-Aw has said, it works with Oracle 12c or higher. For previous versions where computed default values are not supported, you may use triggers. 
Here's a patch for that

```
diff --git a/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml b/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml
index dbdae03..702d0ba 100644
--- a/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml
+++ b/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@
     <changeSet id="00000000000001" author="jhipster">
         <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_USER" startValue="1000" incrementBy="1"/>
         <createTable tableName="JHI_USER">
-            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}" defaultValueComputed="SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL">
+            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                 <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
             </column>
             <column name="login" type="varchar(50)">
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@
             <column name="last_modified_by" type="varchar(50)"/>
             <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
         </createTable>
-        
+
         <createTable tableName="JHI_AUTHORITY">
             <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                 <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
@@ -119,10 +119,10 @@
                   file="config/liquibase/users_authorities.csv"
                   separator=";"
                   tableName="JHI_USER_AUTHORITY"/>
-                  
+
         <createSequence sequenceName="SEQ_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT" startValue="1000" incrementBy="1"/>
         <createTable tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT">
-            <column name="event_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}" defaultValueComputed="SEQ_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT.NEXTVAL">
+            <column name="event_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}" >
                 <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
             </column>
             <column name="principal" type="varchar(255)">
@@ -162,5 +162,37 @@
                                  referencedColumnNames="event_id"
                                  referencedTableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT"/>
     </changeSet>
-    
+
+    <changeSet id="defaultValueComputedOnAutoIncrementFields" author="cirovladimir" dbms="mysql,h2,postgresql">
+        <addDefaultValue tableName="JHI_USER"
+                         columnName="id" columnDataType="bigint" defaultValueComputed="SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL"/>
+        <addDefaultValue tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT"
+                         columnName="event_id" columnDataType="bigint" defaultValueComputed="SEQ_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT.NEXTVAL"/>
+    </changeSet>
+
+    <changeSet id="triggerOnAutoIncrementFields" author="cirovladimir" dbms="oracle">
+        <createProcedure>
+            CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_JHI_USER_ID
+            BEFORE INSERT
+            ON JHI_USER
+            FOR EACH ROW
+            DECLARE
+            BEGIN
+            SELECT SEQ_USER.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
+            END TRG_JHI_USER_ID;
+        </createProcedure>
+        <createProcedure>
+            CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT_ID
+            BEFORE INSERT
+            ON JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT
+            FOR EACH ROW
+            DECLARE
+            BEGIN
+            SELECT SEQ_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.EVENT_ID FROM DUAL;
+            END TRG_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT_ID;
+        </createProcedure>
+    </changeSet>
+
+
+
 </databaseChangeLog>
```